# Sort Criteria - sort by user role

Tags: views, users

I have 7 roles in my project.
I arranged them by weight in admin/people/permissions/roles page
Add the sort criteria Global:PHP with code

```
return $row1->rid;
```

But users display with no sort on role weight on page.

Answer (score 2):

Look for these solutions:

[In Views, how can I show users with one role before all other users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41723/in-views-how-can-i-show-users-with-one-role-before-all-other-users)

[Role Weights](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_weights)

This way you can get your desired result. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But first issue is not working for me (strange, but have no some elements). About second - installed module, but can't understand where can I use tokens for sorting (yes, i'm new in Drupal)